# Query using collections

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have this Entity in which I need to query for:

```
@Entity
public class Resource implements Serializable {   
    @Id    
    private Long id;
    private List<String> key;
}
```

Here is the query:

```
List<String> keyPath = key.getFullPath();
Resource result = ofy().load().type(Resource.class).filter("key =", keyPath).first().get();
```

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A collection of values is not allowed.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:140)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query$FilterPredicate.<init>(Query.java:867)
```

Question:

- Is is possible to do a query using collections like List as query value?
- Is it possible with Objectify query or native Datastore query?
- If not, what is the approach to doing this kind of query

The idea is to query get the `Resource` entity having the same list of strings (`key` field) as with the query value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with the `IN` operator?

```
Resource result = ofy().load().type(Resource.class).filter("key IN ", keyPath).first().get();
```

Comment: Looks like I was missing @Index in the field

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for retrieving information from datastore with the single value for the property having list (using Objectify),

```
Query<Resource> resultset = ofy().load().type(Resource.class).filter("key",keyPath);
Resource firstResult = resultset.first().now();
```